# android some times menu does not show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I am using options menu in message fragment where I can add friends from menu. I can navigate to this fragment from activity or fragment. When I launch this message fragment, menu is working fine. When I do navigate through other screen and come to message fragment menu disappears. After using/navigating in the application for 4-5 minutes, menu starts behaving randomly.

Strange behavior is, when I do launch message fragment from activity, menu always works well. This behaves randomly when I launch it from fragment.

Here is my code

```
    public class MessagesFragment extends BaseFragment{
private static final String TAG = MessagesFragment.class.getSimpleName();
Context mContext;
View mView;
private ListView listBuddy;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mContext = activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((InnerActivity)getActivity()).setActionbarTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.my_buddies));

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
    listBuddy = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewFindBuddy);
    this.mView = v;
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_add:

        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Why you have `menu.clear();` this in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`??

Comment: action bar menu were getting duplicated. For that I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787318/actionbar-items-are-duplicating 
So I added that line

Comment: Found strange behavior, when I do launch message fragment from activity, menu always works well. This behaves randomly when I launch it from fragment.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in your activity :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But I have used different menus in fragments, so I cannot add specific menu in activity.. :(